# VS Code: "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found" error

Tags: javascript, debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have looked everywhere and I still have issue debugging TypeScript inside VS Code. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169259/how-to-debug-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-code) thread but still I am not able to hit my breakpoints placed inside a TypeScript file, hitting the breakpoints in .js files all works fine.

So here is the simplest "hello world" project I have set up.

- app.ts:

  ```
  var message: string = "Hello World";

  console.log(message);
  ```
- tsconfig.json

  ```
  {
      "compilerOptions": {
          "target": "es5",
          "sourceMap": true
      }
  }
  ```
- launch.json

  ```
  {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
          {
              "name": "Launch",
              "type": "node",
              "request": "launch",
              "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
              "stopOnEntry": false,
              "args": [],
              "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
              "preLaunchTask": null,
              "runtimeExecutable": null,
              "runtimeArgs": [
                  "--nolazy"
              ],
              "env": {
                  "NODE_ENV": "development"
              },
              "externalConsole": false,
              "sourceMaps": true,
              "outDir": null
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

I have generated the js.map files by running the `tsc --sourcemap app.ts` command.

After all of those steps when I set a breakpoint on the `console.log(message);` row and launch the program (F5) from the "Debug" tab that breakpoint is grayed out saying "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)." I attached a screenshot of what I am observing:

[image]

What am I missing?

Edit:

Hi, I am still stuck on this. I managed to make one sample project that was hitting the break points but after I tried to copy that project to a different location on my HDD the break points again became gray and were not hit. What I did different in this test project was to use inline sourcemaps by compiling the TypeScript files with `tsc app.ts --inlinesourcemap`

I uploaded the mentioned sample project to GitHub so you can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/VladimirAmiorkov/TypeScriptVSCodeDebugTest).

Answer (score 31):

Setting `"outFiles" : ["${workspaceRoot}/compiled/**/*.js"]` solved the issue for me.
 
`"outFiles"` value should match one set in `tsconfig.json` for `outDir` and `mapRoot` which is `${workspaceRoot}` in your case, so try `"outFiles": "${workspaceRoot}/**/*.js"`

Here are my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/compiled/**/*.js"],
        "mapRoot": "compiled"
    },
    "include": [
        "app/**/*",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

and `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/compiled/app.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/compiled",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is small project, where you may see all parameters set https://github.com/v-andrew/ts-template

Comment: Under windows using VSC 1.8.1 and Node.js 8.9.1 i had to make these changes `launch.json`: `"outFiles": [],` instead of `outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/compiled",` and i had to switch from `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",` to `"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\app.js",` so \ instead of /.

Comment: outFiles functionality has changed as of September 2020. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107615

Answer (score 17):

I came across this question while looking for a solution to a similar problem that I was having. Despite being different from OP's problem, it might help others.

Context: I was following the [Visual Studio Code HelloWorld example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript) and found myself unable to stop on break points.

I solved my problem by changing `.vscode/launch.json` so that `"sourceMaps": true` attribute under the Launch configuration was set (it starts default on false).

Comment: Please note: for me, sourceMaps did need to be set to true, but I also had to set outFiles as noted in the next answer.

Comment: Same here! Without, vscode stopped only on `debugger;` (well, at least that. As a litmus test to start with...). – with `"outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/build"` also breakpoints do work nicely...  (so probably, vscode can't reveal source-side breakpoints on the build-side (which it is running, naturally) without...)

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem might be in your 'program' section of launch.json. Try it like this:

```
{
    // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
    "name": "Launch",
    // Type of configuration.
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.ts",
    // Automatically stop program after launch.
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    // Command line arguments passed to the program.
    "args": [],
    // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
    "runtimeExecutable": null,
    // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
    "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
    // Environment variables passed to the program.
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
    "sourceMaps": true,
    // If JavaScript source maps are enabled, the generated code is expected in this directory.
    "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

Comment: I changed the "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js" to "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.ts" but still the breakpoint in the .ts file is not being hit, only the one in the .js file is being hit.

Comment: Can you follow the answer I gave in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606423/visual-studio-code-debug-node-js-through-typescript/35608348#35608348 Starting with checking paths in map.js file. It should help you to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: When running the sample project from that thread (https://github.com/7brutus7/stackoverflow) I do get a breakpoint in the .ts file. Unfortunately I am totally lost how that works in that project and not in my sampler project.

Comment: In your original code - do you use locally installed tsc or global (check tasks.json)? In the previous thread there where some issues with the global instance.

Comment: I use the global tsc, in the auto generated tasks.json it is set like this ""command": "tsc""

The tsc version is 1.8.7

Answer (score 5):

Facing the same issue and solved it by correcting the path to `.ts` files.
My project contains `src` and `dist` dirs and the problem was that the generated `.map` files didn't have the correct path to the `src` dir.

The fix - `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceRoot": "../src"
    }
}
```

Initially, my `sourceRoot` was pointing to `src` and there is no `src` dir inside `dist`.

Also, `sourceMaps` should be set to `true` inside `launch.json`.

Comment: This is a good summary of major issues. sourceMaps in launch.json is required as stated, but I just had an issue due to having changed my launch.json "program" value to point to a .js file instead of a .ts one. VS Code hit breakpoint.. Working again! Cheerz!

Comment: I spent so much time working on this and your tip about `sourceRoot` turned out to be the solution.  Ugh!  I wish this wasn't so hard to get working.  I wish when you run `tsc --init` the comment associated with the `sourceRoot` field as more descriptive and explained what structure it actually expects for the files so you could figure out what the right value was.  In any case, THANKS!

Answer (score 5):

After ripping my hair out all day, I finally got it to work.

The problem is there's three files to fiddle with - launch.json, tsconfig.json, and webpack.config.js so it's all combinatorial.

the diagnosticLogging was key to helping me figure it out.

Microsoft please make this easier...  Really, vscode could have figured this out or at least guided me more on the process.

Anyway here's what finally worked in my launch.json:

```
"url": "http://localhost:8080/",
"sourceMaps": true,
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
"diagnosticLogging": true,
"sourceMapPathOverrides": { "webpack:///src/*": "${workspaceRoot}/src/*" }
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
"outDir": "dist",
"sourceMap": true
```

my webpack.config.js:

```
output: {
   path: 'dist/dev',
   filename: '[name].js'
},
...
module: {
    loaders: [...],
    preLoaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
    }]
}
...
plugins: [
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin(),
    ...
],
devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, for some reason I had to add that sourceMapPathOverride as well.

Comment: `diagnosticLogging` is now deprecated...  use `trace` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Facing the same issue and solved it by correcting `"webRoot"` config in launch.json.
[Here's my workspace's explorer view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xth3.png)

Since the compiling result `main.js and main.js.map` are in  `"./project/www/build"` directory, I change the `"webRoot"` entry to `"${workspaceRoot}/project/www/build"` from `"${workspaceRoot}"`, and it worked!

The launch.json file is as follow:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:8100",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/project/www/build"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "url": "http://localhost:8100",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/project/www/build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me.

I then realised the `program` attribute in my `launch.json` was pointing to the `.js` file, but my project is a TypeScript project.

I changed it to point to the TypeScript (`.ts`) file, and set the `outFiles` attribute to point to where the compiled code lives:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server/Server.ts",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"]
}
```

This solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is really only one way to resolve this and that is to look at the source map path that is actually used.

Add the following line to `launch.json`:

```
"diagnosticLogging": true,
```

Among a lot of other stuff, your console will have lines like these:

```
SourceMap: mapping webpack:///./src/main.ts => C:\Whatever\The\Path\main.ts, via sourceMapPathOverrides entry - "webpack:///./*": "C:/Whatever/The/Path/*"
```

And then you just tweak your `sourceMapPathOverrides` to make the path match to your actual source path. I've found that I needed slightly different configuration for different projects, so understanding how to debug this really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but you can check this post on github [Test globbing support for the `outFiles` attribute in the launch config #12254](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12254).

Basically in the new version of vscode, you must now use the glob pattern with the property `outFiles`in your task.json.

I had a simlar issue. I fixed by indicating the output dir with `outFiles`

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of time wasted on resolving this issue, it turned out the best way is to turn on debugging trace by adding the following line in launch.json.

```
"trace": true
```

And see where the problem actually is. 
Your debug console will output something in the lines of:

```
Verbose logs are written to: /Users/whatever/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/blah/blah/debugadapter.txt
```

Among a lot of other stuff, your console will have lines like these:

```
SourceMap: mapping webpack:///./src/index.ts => C:\Some\Path\index.ts, via sourceMapPathOverrides entry - "webpack:///./*": "C:/Some/Path/*"
```

Use sourceMapPathOverride to fix it to actually match your path. The property "trace" used to be called "diagnosticLogging" which is no longer used.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my config in launch.json for:

`{
      "name": "Debug tests in Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9222,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "*": "${webRoot}/*"
      },
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }`

before was:

`{
      "name": "Debug tests in Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9222,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }`

Include '"sourceMapPathOverrides"' was my solution

Answer (score 0):

This config in launch.json worked:

`{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program - app",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server.ts",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/release/**"],
            "sourceMaps": true
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute to spare some hours of head banging.

I used **Debugger for Chrome** for VS code (you don't need this for webstorm), I would recommend spend 10min reading their [page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome), it will enlighten your world.

After installing the debugger extension, make sure that *source-map* is installed, in my case I also needed *source-map-loader*. Check your **package.json** for that.

My launch.json which is the chrome debugger configuration (all my source files where under **src**) :

```js
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Chrome",
      "port": 9222,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Add `devtool: 'source-map'` to your webpack.config.js. 
Other parameters that generates mapping inlines won't work with Chrome Debugger (they mention that on their page).

This is an example:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Tutorial",
      inject: "body",
      template: "src/html/index.html",
      filename: "index.html"
    }),
    new DashboardPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',  
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["es2017", "react"],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs']          
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true
};
```

Then you run your webpack: `webpack-dev-server --devtool source-map --progress --port 8080, I used webpack-dev-server but it has same options as webpack.

When you do that you must see a **.map** file of your generated app. If not then come back and verify your setup.

Now in VS Code switch to Debug Console and run `.scripts`. This is a very useful command because it shows you what generated code is mapped to which source.

Something like this:
`- webpack:///./src/stores/friendStore.js (/Users/your_user/Developer/react/tutorial/src/stores/friendStore.js)`

If this is wrong then you have to verify your **sourceMapPathOverrides** in your launch.json, examples are available on the [extension's page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

yes! in my case changing this in launch.json file solve the problem:

```
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
    "webpack:///./*":   "${webRoot}/*",
    "webpack:///*":     "*",
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular I have found that I always point my folder directory to the `src` folder - that way my work-space is not so cluttered with root files that I never use. But this has given me several problems in the past especially when using VSCode, since many of the functionality seems to me to look at the folder structure, and start from there to run your files. (Expecting some of the missing files)

So I had this exact same problem with this error message, and learning from past experience I realized that I opened my project one folder deep, instead of the root `<app name>` folder. So I just closed my project and opened it one folder up (so that all the other files are also included in the folder structure) and my problem was immediately fixed.

I also believe that many of the above answers about changing your files and folder structure are workarounds to this problem of not opening your work project at the root folder, what ever framework/language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to restart my express server and then reattach the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this thread and trying almost all methods I could find to no avail, I Google'd some more and stumbled upon this *weeery* interesting change they made in VSCode 1.49.0, in September 2020. In a nuthshell, **outFiles** does not work as before.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107615

Answer (score -2):

if you switch to visual studio type script project you can debug ts files normally
i think the issue in app.js.map generation file 
here is sample from **visual studio** app.js.map

> {"version":3,"file":"app.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["app.ts"],"names":["HelloWorld","HelloWorld.constructor"],"mappings":"AAAA;IACIA,oBAAmBA,OAAcA;QAAdC,YAAOA,GAAPA,OAAOA,CAAOA;IAEjCA,CAACA;IACLD,iBAACA;AAADA,CAACA,AAJD,IAIC;AAED,IAAI,KAAK,GAAG,IAAI,UAAU,CAAC,kBAAkB,CAAC,CAAC;AAC/C,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,CAAC"}

vs **visual studio code** app.js.map

> {"version":3,"file":"app.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../app.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AACA;IACI,oBAAmB,OAAc;QAAd,YAAO,GAAP,OAAO,CAAO;IAEjC,CAAC;IACL,iBAAC;AAAD,CAAC,AAJD,IAIC;AACD,IAAI,KAAK,GAAC,IAAI,UAAU,CAAC,aAAa,CAAC,CAAC;AACxC,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,CAAC;AAC3B,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,CAAC"}

try to replace it and try again don't forget to consider directory hierarchy of sources