# Typescript debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-code

i tried this solution: [how to debug typescript files in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169259/how-to-debug-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-code)

But if I make a breakpoint in my .ts files it's says the file not found for the debugger. The breakpoint in the .js files works. The Sourcemaps exists.

the launch configuration:

```
    {
        "name": "DEBUG",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app.ts",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "preLaunchTask": null,
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "externalConsole": false,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/cmpl"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem with your tsconfig.json. You must check if config contains correct `sourceRoot` compiler option set to the right path to your .ts sources.

`sourceMap` also must be set to true. You can double check path correctness, inspecting any of your .js.map files, where `sources` and `sourceRoot` fields must point to the right path to your .ts source file.

Comment: Did you check path to `.ts` file inside any of your `.js.map`? Is it relative or absolute? Is it points to correct location?

Comment: for an example the sourcmap from my IndexController is `"sources":["controllers/IndexController.ts"]`

Comment: Is IndexController.ts file in "controllers" folder, relatively to your IndexController.js.map? It looks like your config points to different folders for .js and sources.

Comment: IndexController.js/.js.map is in `./cmpl/controllers` and IndexController.ts is in `./src/controllers`

Comment: You can set the sourceRoot compiler option in the your tsconfig `sourceRoot: "src"`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions to make it work:

- Make sure your tsconfig.json points to the right src/ and output directories, something like

  ```
  {
      "compilerOptions": {
          "module": "commonjs",
          "target": "es6",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "rootDir": "src",
          "outDir": "cmpl"
      }
  }
  ```
- You should have a build task (.vscode/tasks.json) to make sure the output is up-to-date

  ```
  {
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "command": "tsc",
      "isShellCommand": true,
      "args": ["-p", "."],
      "showOutput": "silent",
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
  }
  ```

And in your launch.json
`"preLaunchTask": "tsc"`

Comment: to the tsconfig. It did, if not would be able to launch the server. The Server runs, but i cannot make breakpoints in my .ts files. And the build task works as well.

Comment: @R3Tech hmm that's strange. At this point it's difficult to say without examining the project closer :)

Comment: i have a cmpl and src folder. In this are the app.ts/js file and folder like routes, controllers, models and more.In my root dir, where the cmpl and src folder are, is the tsconfig, package.json, gulpfile.js and other project files.

Comment: then I take it you're placing the breakpoint in a different file rather than app.ts? I'd advise to try placing breakpoints in app.ts and trace them to find out where you can't hit breakpoints anymore.