# Can't debug current typescript file in VS Code because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.17, and my objective is to debug the *current* typescript file. I have a build task running, so I always have a corresponding javascript file like this:

```
src/folder1/folder2/main.ts
src/folder1/folder2/main.js
```

I have tried with the following launch.json configuration:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Current File",
  "program": "${file}",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/${fileDirname}**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

But I get the error: `Cannot launch program '--full-path-to-project--/src/folder1/folder2/main.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.`

But the corresponding JavaScript file exists!

tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "watch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true
    // "types": []
},
"include": [
    "src",
    "test"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
]}
```

Comment: Added https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236103/428486 with solutions same dir and separate dir, both of which I confirmed work in vscode, hope it helps!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The configuration for your `outFiles` points to the wrong directory.

Replacing your `launch.json` config with this would fix it:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Current File",
  "program": "${file}",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "outFiles": ["${fileDirname}/*.js"]
}
```

From the [vscode launch.json variable reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference):

> `${fileDirName}` the current opened file's dirname

should be the directory you need.

Note that you can also use `"outFiles": ["${fileDirname}/**/*.js"]` to include subdirectories.

The configuration you're using adds the following directory:

```
"${workspaceFolder}/${fileDirname}**/*.js"
```

Which translates to something like:

```
"/path/to/root/path/to/root/src/folder1/folder2/**/*.js"
```

i.e. the path to the root is in there twice, making it an invalid path.

**If your .js files are on a different `outDir`**: simply use the path to such directory. Typescript `sourceMaps` will do the rest.

For example, if you put your `.js` files in a `dist` directory:

```
"outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"]
```

Comment: did some tests and you nailed it - outFiles is the property that made it possible. I guess my problem was that I did not think the system was "smart" enough to lkp the file with help of sourcemaps, but now it's more clear thanks to your answer. In other words, this would not work with sourcemaps disabled?

Comment: Correct, It would not work with source maps disabled. Not super clear in the docs but it doesn't work if you disable sourceMaps in `tsconfig.json`: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-maps

Comment: I have almost and identical problem, have tried the above solutions but the problem continues, anyone can help me out ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74281385/cant-debug-typescript-extension-vs-code-because-corresponding

Answer (score 22):

The problem may be with your map files and not with configuration.

Before trying anything else you want to make sure your paths that you are using in your launch configuration are correct.

You can do so by substituting the paths with absolute paths on your system temporarily to see if it works.

**If it does not work you should:**

Check your tsconfig and make sure `mapRoot` under `compilerOptions` is not set to anything. This is what official documentation has to say about it:

> Specifies the location where debugger should locate map files instead
>   of generated locations. Use this flag if the .map files will be
>   located at run-time in a different location than the .js files. The
>   location specified will be embedded in the sourceMap to direct the
>   debugger where the map files will be located.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

In most of the cases, you don't really want to set it to anything.

Also, make sure that

`"sourceMap"`: true`

is set in `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json and map files are getting generated.

Comment: The debugger is working if given abseloute paths. mapRoot is not set - I will edit the original question so the tsconfig.json is included. Lastely - map files are getting generated.

Comment: If it is working with absolute paths, then it obviously means that you need to set "program" and "outFiles" correctly. I set both like this: `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/backend/src/app.ts", "outFiles": [ "${workspaceFolder}/backend/build/**/*.js"]`
 ${workspaceFolder} gives you the location of home folder of your project. From there you can navigate to your files. You can have a look at my full configuration in my answer below. stackoverflow.com/questions/31169259/…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47215246/7022062  <-- fixing link that Aakash Malhotra provided in his comment

Comment: VS Code Insiders currently (Jan '19) comments out SourceMap by default (tsconfig.json).

I had to uncomment Sourcemap:true otherwise source maps aren't created and the default debug launch config in launch.json will cause VS-C to throw the "corresponding Javascript files can't be found" error.

You'd expect the default behaviour of VS-C would be to generate source maps but apparently this is not the case.

Comment: I've been using VScode 1.46.1 and I'm about to test my last and tenth launch.json...  Note that it is written in plain text at the bottom of VsCode help page "cannot find corresponding JavaScript"  
This is a serious bummer for newcomers to TypeScript!  
Putting absolute path increased the number of errors in the log, so it was definitely a mark on the right direction.  
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone else bumps into this: if you're using webpack to build your project, you have to use a [devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) setting that generates VS Code compatible source maps. Through trial and error, `cheap-module-source-map` and `source-map` work well. I ended up adding this to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
devtool: env.production ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-source-map'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to enable source maps in your tsconfig.json

```
"sourceMap": true,
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it fixed by adding **`"sourceMap": true`** in `tsconfig.json`

`launch.json` looks like

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
    "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
    "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/build/**/*.js"]
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the program file that you want to run should have the focus before you execute, otherwise you'll get the 'Cannot find Javascript' error dialog. Especially when the file you are executing is not a Javascript or a Typescript file. Becuase, in the default `launch.json` file, configuration `"program": "${file}"` is specified. That means the file that is currently being displayed on the screen will be executed.

So for example: If you are in a non-js or non-ts file, say, `tsconfig.json` or `launch.json` and you click Run command, then you'll get that error dialog.

### Properly setting up a Typescript project in VS Code

Make sure you have Typescript and Node.js installed on your machine before creating the project.

**1.Intialize in the terminal**

In the terminal create a new folder for your project.

```
mkdir MyProject
```

Change the current directory to the folder you made above.

```
cd MyProject
```

Initialize the project to enable Typescript. This will create the *tsconfig.json* file.

```
tsc --init
```

Open this folder in VS Code. This command works from MacOS. You can open manually too.

```
code .
```

**2.Configure the output directory**

Now go to the file *tsconfig.json* and add the following lines to the `compilerOptions`. Yes, you need to specify the output directory here in *tsconfig.json* instead of *launch.json*. VS Code will always look for files in default `outDir` of *launch.json* which is `${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js`.

```
"outDir": "./out",  /* Specify .js output files. */
"sourceMap": true   /* Generate corresponding .map files. */
```

### Running/Debugging the project

Write a simple program to test and run: `welcome.ts`

```
console.log('Welcome to Typescript');
```

**1.Build**

Now Click Run Build Task (Shift + Command(Ctrl) + B) from the Terminal menu of the VS Code and type the following command and press enter:

```
tsc: watch - tsconfig.json
```

You need to Run Build Task once when you first open the project. This will start watching for code changes in the project.

**2.Run**

Now go to the Typescript program that you want to run (Make sure your program file `.ts` has the focus). 
From the Run menu:

Click Start Debugging for debug (F5)

OR

Click Run Without Debugging (Ctrl + F5)

Output will be displayed in the Debug Console.

That's it. It may seem overwhelming at first, but it's easy once you get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked in my case:

Go into your `gulpfile.js` and find the line that contains `sourcemaps.write()`. Change this line to

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '../lib' }))
```

Rebuild your project and try running the debugger again. [Credit goes to roblourens on GitHub.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41851#issuecomment-359061243) He linked [this page,](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript#source-maps) which was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a weird situation where my machine worked perfectly fine based on @lucascaro suggestions but on someone else's computer with the same version of vscode, node, ts, etc. I could still see the error message.

So, if you have followed all the instructions from @lucascaro and you are still seeing the error message try adding this to your launch.json configuration after the program property, like this:

```
{
  ...
  "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
  ...
}
```

This addition made it work on the second machine, but if i added it to mine it would not work anymore.

So if you are in a place where it still fails give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was setting the working directory to some directory other than the file's directory in `launch.json`:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/dist"
```

Perhaps it could be a bug in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Base url generated as

`"baseUrl": "./",`

inside tsconfig.json

I changed it to

`"baseUrl": "./src"`

and the mapping started working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added `"sourceRoot": "../../"` in the compiler options of tsconfig.json.

Check the relative path `"sourceRoot": ""` generated in app.js.map files as `"sourceRoot":"../../","sources":["src/app.ts"]` indicates the absolute path of your .ts files.

Answer (score -3):

Hi I had the same problem. You just need to add to the **user path** or the **global path variable** the path you have installed npm.

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

[image]