# How to Debug Node.js Applications Running Typescript Inside docker-compose wtih VSCode?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, ts-node

### Goal

My goal is to be able to debug multiple Node.js services running in docker-compose with the help of VSCode. But there are some challenges involved:

1. [ts-node-dev](https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev) has no documentation for VSCode debugging. But since it is just a wrapper around [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) (which has native support for VSCode dbugging) this should be possible with something like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51080377/8586803). Or do I have to use `ts-node` when I want to debug?
2. How to debug the code that is running inside a Docker container? For that purpose I might do something similar as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Docker-TypeScript). But they compile the TYpescript to Javascript manually, which I don't want to do.
3. How to coordinate multiple services? Because I have multiple services, would I have to choose which one I want to debug or is it possible to launch the debugger for all of the services at once?

### The project

I've made a small [sample project](https://github.com/flolu/typescript-docker-vscode-debug) with the following structure. There are two services (gateway and hello) running in docker-compose.

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
docker-compose.yaml
services
  hello
    index.ts
  gateway
    index.ts
```

After running `docker-compose up --build`:

- http://localhost:3000 - gateway responds directly
- http://localhost:3000/hello - gateway sends response from hello service

Here is the [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/flolu/typescript-docker-vscode-debug/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml) file I use to start the project in development mode.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  gateway:
    image: node:lts-alpine
    working_dir: /
    volumes:
      - ./package.json:/package.json
      - ./tsconfig.json:/tsconfig.json
      - ./services/gateway:/services/gateway
      - ./node_modules:/node_modules
    command: yarn run ts-node-dev services/gateway
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  hello:
    image: node:lts-alpine
    working_dir: /
    volumes:
      - ./package.json:/package.json
      - ./tsconfig.json:/tsconfig.json
      - ./services/hello:/services/hello
      - ./node_modules:/node_modules
    command: yarn run ts-node-dev services/hello
```

Note that I use `ts-node-dev` to run the services, which automatically restarts the servers when a change in the code as detected, but I would be willing to use something else if necessary.

Comment: just a thought, have you tried VSCode remote containers extension https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers ?

Comment: @V.i.K.i looks interesting. But the problem I see at first glance is that it runs inside **one** container. But I have many containers. But I will take a closer look at it :)

Comment: Sure. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a video explaining how to make this work.

https://odysee.com/@flolu:7/docker-typescript-debug:3?r=HFBL1PfaSVqKsaYbQDRH3GZZp78ch6CR

And this is the source code: https://github.com/flolu/docker-typescript-debug