# How to debug TypeScript in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

1. Installing ts-node and typescript locally √
2. Add a launch.json file √

```
{
    "name": "Current TS Tests File",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
    "args": ["-r", "ts-node/register", "${relativeFile}"],
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

Open up `index.ts`, and start the debugger...

```
Process exited with code 1
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"
```

Comment: if you don't compile TS file into JS file you can't debug, read the TS VSC doc page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to debug typescript files in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169259/how-to-debug-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

There is two common options for this.

**Use NodeJS:**

NodeJS only interprets JavaScript, therefore you will have to cross compile your TypeScript first and enable source maps to use breakpoints.
VSCode docs have a thorough [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial) for this.

**Use Deno:**

Deno interprets TypeScript, therefore it does not require cross compilation. VSCode does not support Deno out of the box, but there is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=denoland.vscode-deno) for it, and note that you also need [Deno CLI](https://deno.land/#installation) in order for it to work.