# Run a file in command line with lanuch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a TypeScript script that process files via this command line:

```bash
npx ts-node script.ts file.txt
```

What I need is to be able lo launch this command line in VSCode with F5 and see the output in the terminal.
I don't need debugging. I just want to launch this single line and receive output, with `file.txt` replaced with the currently opened file.

I tried to create `launch.json` for this but the documentation is so node/debugger specific and off my topic that I couldn't find any clues on how to launch a simple command in the terminal.

For instance, here is what I tried:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run script",
            "type": "shell",
            "program": "npx ts-node ${workspaceFolder}/script.ts ${file}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: if you don't need debugging then what you are looking for is a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Comment: @starball thanks. But the question is the same: how to configure a task to launch `npx ts-node script.ts ${file}` with F5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to debug typescript files in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169259/how-to-debug-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @starball no. I don't need to debug ts. I specifically mentioned that in the beginning. I need to launch a ts script on a given `.txt` file with F5.

Comment: and yet the solution you found falls into the same category as those found in the question I linked.

Comment: @starball which category? I need to execute a random shell command, not to run a `node.exe`. I need a solution, not "a question in the same category". The answers there do not have `runtimeExecutable` which is critical to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, launching a single command via F5 is more complicated than it should be.
Still, this `launch.json` can do the trick:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npx",
            "args": [
                "ts-node",
                "${workspaceFolder}/script.ts",
                "${file}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: note (in my case): \
1. you can use `tsx` instead of `ts-node` / `ts-node/esm` \
1. if you install `tsx` globally, without involving `npx`, it will be faster \
1. eg: `{       "type": "node",       "request": "launch",       "name": "Run ts file one click with tsx (globally installed, faster)",       "runtimeExecutable": "tsx",       "runtimeArgs": [],       "program": "${file}",       "args": [],       "skipFiles": [         "<node_internals>/**",         "node_modules/**"       ]     }`